# How to send unmanaged function pointers from dll to another unmanaged function in other dll through managed code?

Tags: c#, dll, function, unmanaged, managed

I have this problem, which I am dealing with for some time already. At start, I have two dlls with unmanaged code (let's say... dll_1, dll_2) and managed aplication in c#. What i'm supposed to do is to get pointers to unmanaged functions in dll_1 in managed code, pack it into structure, and send this structure as an argument to unmanaged function in dll_2. Have anyone dealt with that kind of problem before maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't do anything in managed code but the DLLs live in the same process, just use an `IntPtr` (is automatically 32 or 64 bits depending on the platform) to pass the unmanaged pointer around. You can of course also insert the `IntPtr` into your struct and use it as argument or return value when using an external call (e.g. `[DllImport('YourDll')] static extern IntPtr ImportedFunction();`).

However, to give you more information, it would be necessary to know more about the DLL calls and their data structures.

Comment: ...but make sure the DLL's really share the same process (and apartment if you're doing COM)...

Comment: @Pontus, you're of course right, but passing around unmanaged pointers is not a typical COM task, and dealing with mixed address spaces isn't either. So I was just assuming the simple/obvious case.